How to scan and extract UUID, Major, and Minor values from BLE devices using Java?
I am trying to scan BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) devices using Java and extract specific information such as the UUID, Major, and Minor values from their advertisement packets.
I have set up Bluetooth scanning and can detect nearby BLE devices, but I'm unsure how to parse the advertisement data to extract the required fields.
Here's what I've implemented so far:
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
BluetoothLeScanner scanner = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();

if (scanner != null) {
    scanner.startScan(new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
            byte[] scanRecord = result.getScanRecord().getBytes();

            // How do I parse scanRecord to get UUID, Major, and Minor?
            System.out.println("Device: " + device.getName() + " (" + device.getAddress() + ")");
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
            System.err.println("Scan failed with error: " + errorCode);
        }
    });
}


